# How to return json response in symfony 3.4

Tags: php, json, symfony

this is a newbie question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I am trying return a JSON response from a controller in Symfony 3.4.

In the controller I have:

```
namespace MegBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use MegBundle\Entity\message;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

class MegController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/message/board/page/{page}", name = "message_board", defaults = {"page" = 1}, requirements = {"page" = "\d+"})
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showMeg(Request $request, $page)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        if ($request->query->get("DESC") != null) {
            $orderById = "DESC=ID";
            $orderby = 'DESC';
        }

        if ($request->query->get("DESC") == null) {
            $orderById = "ASC=ID";
            $orderby = 'ASC';
        }

        $per = 5;
        $start = ($page-1)*$per;
        $query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("r")
            ->from("MegBundle:message", "r")
            ->orderBy('r.id', $orderby)
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($per);
        $data = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
        $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false);
        $count = count($paginator);
        $pages = ceil($count/$per);
        return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => ['name' => $data->getName(),
        'mes' => $data->getMes(),
        'update_time' => $data->getUpdateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]]);
    }
```

But I get

> Call to a member function getName() on array.

I hope i can get JosnResponse like this

> {"result":"ok","ret":{"name":[{"name":"AAA","mes":"1234","update_time":"2019-09-20 10:54:50"},{"name":"AAA","mes":"1234","update_time":"2019-09-20 11:08:53"},{"name":"Lai","mes":"AppleAppleappleAPPLE","update_time":"2019-09-20 11:11:09"}]}

Comment: Please update with what your question is specifically, as well as the full error code. This will make your question more clear to potential answerers.

Comment: `$data` is an array of objects (most likely), so you probably want - for example - `array_map` that or loop over it to create your response array?

Comment: `->getArrayResult()` returns an array of results. You can access `$data[0]`, `$data[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $data is an array of data, (see `$query->getQuery()->getArrayResult()` )

So your are trying to get attributes from an array instead of accessing them from the appropriate object.

Since you are already getting an array result and you want to put this in the name part of your json, you could just change your **jsonResponse** to :

```
return new JsonResponse(['result' => 'ok', 'ret' => ['name' => $data]]);
```

You may need to change your **query** to specify which attributes to get and not get the whole entity, in your case **name**, **mes** and **update_time**.

Something like :

```
 $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("r.name, r.mes, r.update_time")
            //...
```